# params hash problems with a hidden form post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this hidden form:

```
<form action="/event_signup" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<%= session[:current_user]%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<%= event.id%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token%>">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
</form>
```

this is my event_attendances controller:

```
class EventAttendancesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @event_attendance = EventAttendance.new(attendance_params)
        if @event_attendance.save
            flash[:success] = "Signed up for event successfully"
        else
            flash[:danger] = "An error occured whilst trying to sign you up for an event"
        end
        redirect_to root_url
    end

    private
        def attendance_params
            params.require(:event_attendance).permit(:event_id, :user_id)
        end
end
```

my route is set up as so:

```
post 'event_signup' => 'event_attendances#create'
```

however I get an error when I click the submit form button:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in EventAttendancesController#create
```

and when I try and see my params hash in the console I receive a name error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `params'
```

But I can see on the error page that my params hash is looking as it should:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"user_id"=>"1",
"event_id"=>"1",
"authenticity_token"=>"FskE5u1cxfN4JklMfM/JqKtg3t45tyP1z6ivUVmyLx+zlY7aShQDn+eF6aoOXp/StH6svsawXVtSCZcfe4UcsQ=="}
```

And here is my event attendance model:

```
class EventAttendance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
end
```

Comment: does the POST create data?

Comment: What does your model look like!

Comment: I updated my question with the model

Comment: params is not available in the console! Thus you get NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' because your are not in the scope of a request ...

Comment: really? I think I have checked my params before in the console, but nevermind that, then why am I getting "param is missing or the value is empty: event_attendance" error?

Comment: ah ok. Your Form is not mapping to the right Model.

<%= form_for @event_attendance do |f| %>
  #form items.

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>

should look like something like this

Comment: aham, thanks. Just wanted to ask another thing is there a way of doing the form the html way because I really want to be able to make custom forms

Comment: You can make custom forms, but you need to do it the 'Rails way'!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are having is with your `form` definition.

It should look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @event_attendance do |f| %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag(:user_id, session[:current_user]) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag(:event_id, event.id) %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

I would suggest that you create a new rails project and then create a scaffold in that new project. There you will see how rails builds up forms and it's connections with Model and Controller.

I would also suggest you read up on Rails Form Helpers here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Also look at the simple form gem for better development, helps a lot.

Comment: Oh no, I am aware of the form_for helper I used for my user model and my event model, I was just trying to see if I can do the form the other way, and didn't realise it raised a problem.

Comment: oh, wait, when use your form I get the exact same problem

Comment: nevermind, I got where the problem was coming from, event_attendance isnt a resource so i just had to manually create the object form the params hash and not having the attendance_params method